# Electron - How can I install or use a third party dependency like a brew or apt-get package in my app?

Tags: electron

Currently I want to build a desktop app which is using a third party package that can be installed trough `apt-get` or `brew` but I do not know how to inject this dependency on my electron app.

I want to avoid ask the user to install this dependency before of use my app like "Hey to use this app you should have the Package A installed.".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm thinking you could do this by listening for the squirrel install event, when the event occurs install the dependency in the application folder. Not really sure how you would do this programmatically, but a good place to start would be 
here: https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the installer (Preferred). For example, You can create a debian for your app.
In the makefile of the debian, you can check if module is present or not, if not install.

OR

You can do it in the app first boot,
You can check if the user's system already has that module or not using child_process (spawning a terminal & executing a cmd to check if the module is present) or by writing a native node module to do the same.

If the module is not present, you can use child_process module to execute the command to install that module.